why is my autocomplete textbox event TextChanged running so slow with VB.NET
I'm Trying autocomplete with textbox event TextChanged but running so slow with VB.NET.
even though there are only 6 records, is there something wrong with my code, please guide me.
I attached a gif of an example file when I typed "KBE" it ran very slowly and come up with some suggestions until it finishes by itself and then I tried typing "KBT" it ran very slowly too
and come up with some suggestions until it finishes by itself
Thanks
Public Class Form3
    Private iService As New ItemService()
    Private bindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblcodeproduct.Visible = False
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(iService.GetByCodeProduct().Select(Function(n) n.CodeProduct).ToArray())
    End Sub
    Private Sub GetItemData2(ByVal iditem As String)
        Dim item = iService.GetByCodeProductOrBarcode(iditem)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            If String.Equals(iditem, item.CodeProduct, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                TextBox1.Text = item.CodeProduct
            End If
            TextBox2.Text = item.Barcode
        Else
            TextBox2.Clear()
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            lblcodeproduct.Visible = False
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
        Else
            bindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Stock)(CType(iService.GetByCodeProductlike(TextBox1.Text), IList(Of Stock)))}

            If bindingSource1.Count > 0 Then

                lblcodeproduct.Visible = False

                ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
            Else
                lblcodeproduct.Visible = True
            End If
            GetItemData2(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Stock
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
End Class
Public Class ItemService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String

        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetByCodeProduct() As IEnumerable(Of Stock)
        Dim sql = "SELECT CodeProduct AS CodeProduct FROM Items"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stock)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Function GetByCodeProductlike(ByVal CodeProduct As String) As IEnumerable(Of Stock)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT CodeProduct FROM Items WHERE CodeProduct LIKE '%" & CodeProduct & "%'"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stock)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Function GetByCodeProductOrBarcode(ByVal code As String) As Stock
        Dim sql = $"SELECT * FROM Items WHERE CodeProduct = '{code}' or Barcode = '{code}'"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stock)(sql).FirstOrDefault()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class

RESULT AUTOCOMPLETE TEXTBOX


Can you share a sample data (your TRIAL.accdb) and tell us what you are using to read your file (is it System.Data.OleDb?).
Query function is also missing in the code you shared

You should not be querying the database on every TextChanged event. If you're going to type "KBE", what's the point of searching on the first two characters? That's what's slowing it down. You should start/restart a Timer on the TextChanged event and search on the Tick event. You can set the Interval such that time won't expire between keystrokes when someone is typing but will soon after they stop. Something like 300-500 milliseconds should work but you can experiment to see what works best.

@SioGabx ,  thanks. for your respond . I'm proud you're trying to find a solution for me. link this is link for sample data TRIAL.accdb .  tell us what you are using to read your file (is it System.Data.OleDb?). You're right  it is System.Data.OleDb

@SioGabx , and for Query function is also missing in the code you shared I use Dapper nuget

@SioGabx ,
Sorry to bother you, I have a new post maybe you can help me. For this link

You have recursive calls to the TextChanged event because GetItemData2 might change TextBox1.  I have marked the changes I made with '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<.
EDITED - see comments
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Static recursive As Boolean = False '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    If recursive Then Exit Sub '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    recursive = True '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        lblcodeproduct.Visible = False
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
        recursive = False '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Else
        Try '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            bindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Stock)(CType(iService.GetByCodeProductlike(TextBox1.Text), IList(Of Stock)))}

            If bindingSource1.Count > 0 Then

                lblcodeproduct.Visible = False

                ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
            Else
                lblcodeproduct.Visible = True
            End If
            ' the following method might change TextBox1
            '  which results in the .TextChanged event being called again
            ' the changes mean that second call stops the processing of the .TextChanged event
            GetItemData2(TextBox1.Text)
        Finally '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            recursive = False '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        End Try
    End If
End Sub


It might be better to have the recursive = False inside a Finally to ensure that it happens when exiting for any reason (and to protect against a careless early exit that might be added later).

@Craig , It might be better to have the recursive = False inside a Finally to ensure that it happens when exiting for any reason (and to protect against a careless early exit that might be added later). you mean use try catch finally

@Craig - I agree.  I'll edit my response.

@user23548857 For this purpose, the Catch isn't needed unless you want to do something with it---I'd argue to default to not including the Catch.  The goal is just the Finally to ensure that you don't have to remember to include recursive = False at every exit point (and you're covered in the event of an exception that's handled at a higher level in the program without crashing it).

@Craig - in all the gazillion years I have done this I did not know that a Try could exist without a catch.  I did see if you don't have the catch you must have a finally.  THX.
